# Pass One time Amount Along with the Subscription Amount In Paypal Recurring

Tags: php, paypal

How to Pass One time Amount Along with the Subscription Amount In Paypal Recurring..

Say for Example

I am having a verification functionality and user subscription in my project.For Verification People are charged for $5 (One Time) and user subscription for $10/month. But I need pass both the payment in the paypal form as following .

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mytesting@mail.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />

        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe Now" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online." />            
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="User Subscription" />

        <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="15" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
        <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
        <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />           

        <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    </form>
```

My Question is how to use the One time amount(Verification) along with the subscription ??

Answer (score 0):

With the subscription button there is no variable for the one time Payments . One time Payments can only be set up if you use PayPal [API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/) to create the recurring Profiles . As an alternative to this , You can set up a trial period in your subscription button for one day for 5 USD so that they will be charged at the same time for 5 USD and recurring Profile will be charged for the 10 USD/Mon from the next day onward .